# Multiplication in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Consider $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

Now, let us consider the multiplication $(z)^{\lambda} (\bar{z})^{\lambda}$.
Under what condition can I say
\begin{equation}
(z)^{\lambda} (\bar{z})^{\lambda} = \lvert z \lvert ^{2 \lambda}
\end{equation}
would I have to be careful about branches and could someone provide reference where such topic is discussed ?

Comment: Hello :) If $\lambda\in\mathbb Z$ it is true. Unfortunately, i don't know, how it's defined, if $\lambda$ isn't integer.

Comment: see the answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3043519/on-complex-powers-of-complex-numbers?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [On complex powers of complex numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3043519/on-complex-powers-of-complex-numbers)

Comment: If you choose $\arg z \in (-\pi, \pi)$ so $\arg \bar z =-\arg z$ the result holds, so in particular the result holds if you choose the principal branch of the argument (and the logarithm) that avoids the negative real axis;  otherwise, eg if you choose the argument to lie in $(0, 2\pi)$ so you exclude the positive real axis, the result doen;t necessarily hold